# Dynamically calculated variable in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given the following variables in beginning of a procedure:

```
 DECLARE @Flow_ID INT
        ,@Flow_ID_Varchar NVARCHAR(10)
        ,@Flow_Table_Name VARCHAR(200);
```

Through my procedure I want `@Flow_ID_Varchar` and `@Flow_Table_Name` to always be:

```
SET @Flow_ID_Varchar = CAST(@Flow_ID AS NVARCHAR(10));
SET @Flow_Table_Name = 'Flow_'+@Flow_ID_Varchar';
```

My procedure has several blocks, each populates `@Flow_ID` differently and may not be accessed in a given run.

Is there a way to force `@Flow_ID_Varchar` and `@Flow_Table_Name` to be computed dynamically when `@Flow_ID` changes without me using the SET commands each time?

Comment: No, if you mean you change `@Flow_ID` to a new value somewhere in the procedure, and you expect `@Flow_Table_Name` to have a new name after that, you're looking for some kind of macro / preprocessor which doesn't exist in T-SQL.

Comment: But maybe if you describe what you're actually doing with the new table name after every `@Flow_ID` change, we could suggest ways to accomplish that. If you're just trying to avoid multiple assignments after each change, I'd suggest populating a temp table or table variables with all the possibilities, and building the dynamic SQL based on the row you pull from the table. Or focus on optimizing other parts of the code and leaving this part to that's just the way T-SQL works.

Comment: This has a strong code smell to it. I have a feeling you are doing dynamic sql all over the place and using your variables to determine which table(s) to access. This is a very strong indication that the design is extremely problematic.

Comment: Do you really need both variables, e.g. could you simply use `set @Flow_Table_Name = 'Flow_' + Cast( @Flow_Id as NVarChar(10) );`? Once `@Flow_Table_Name` is set you can replace references to `@Flow_Id_NVarChar` with `Substring( @Flow_Table_Name, 6, 10 )` as needed. Aside: `'Flow_'+@Flow_ID_Varchar'` isn't a valid expression due to the curious arrangement of three quotes. And I see [`QuoteName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in your future.

Comment: Sounds like some nasty dynamic SQL going on here, please show your full code